# How can I forcibly stop an Apache Camel exchange?

Tags: apache-camel

I am executing some external processes using `camel-exec` component.

These might be long running (or for whatever business reason), I would like to be able to *kill* some inflightExchanges based on some header values.

So far so good. I can filter the exchange(s) I want to kill, I am marking the exchange with `e.setProperty(Exchange.ROUTE_STOP, Boolean.TRUE);` and removing it from the `InfightRepository`.

But what I need is to **forcibly** stop the execution of the current task and stop the exchange from further routing.

What would you propose? Any ideas?

Comment: How about raising an exception?

Comment: I am, but it is handled after the executable finishes its execution. I want to cancel the 3rd party executable execution right away. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to solve it is the following:

- Created two caches an`execCommandCache<aKey, org.apache.camel.component.exec.ExecCommand>` and a `processCache<org.apache.camel.component.exec.ExecCommand, java.lang.Process>`. Whenever a new executable is started, I am adding it in these caches.
- When I need to cancel an executable I am browsing the InflightRepository and filter on the `aKey` Exchange header. Then I retrieve the `ExecCommand` from the `execCommandCache` and and with this I can find the actual `Process` from `processCache`.
- Finally I am using Zeroturnaround `zt-process-killer` to kill the `Process`. and marking the exchange as done via `exchange.setProperty(Exchange.ROUTE_STOP, Boolean.TRUE);`

  ```
  ProcessUtil.destroyGracefullyOrForcefullyAndWait(process, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  ```

It's not very clean but it does the trick. Hope it helps.